# Updated SDK not running lower SDK?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-2.3

Even though it shows that I have version 25 of the SDK, this app doesn't run. I have downloaded this app from [here](https://github.com/udacity/ud839_Miwok/tree/Starter-code). I got this link from an online course at [Udacity](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud839/lessons/7633778648/concepts/2eef07a4-abb3-448f-8025-8aeb7cf21621).

Please help as to how I should run this app. It's important to learn this as it's a part of my tutorial course.

[image: A screenshot]

Comment: Did you add the newest build tools from the SDK Manager? Please note that the build tools and the SDK Platform are different packages that both need to be installed. Also, please don't add screenshots for showing warnings. Instead. simply add the warning to your project.

Answer (score 0):

In your IDE, the error log shows you that you must install SDK Build tools 23.0.2 and sync your project. Simply click that link and the IDE should handle it for you.

Although you have build tools 25.2.4, 23.0.2 is required to build this project.

Also, the repository from which your project is from also states the prerequisites in the README:

```
Pre-requisites

Android SDK v23
Android Build Tools v23.0.2
Android Support Repository v23.3.0
```